# Python Pandas: groupby 3 dataframes with string, numeric and NaN values to a new dataframe using a common column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I want to groupby (merge?) 3 datasets using the common column `local_authority_name`and respect all the rest of the columns and values (NaN, string, percentage, integer, whatsoever):

Example of some lines of the datasets:

1 `df_total_per_dif`-->

```
             local_authority_name dif_per_2013-2016
0            Barking and Dagenham             61.0%
1                          Barnet             -8.4%
2                        Barnsley            -42.8%
3    Bath and North East Somerset            -45.1%
4                          Bexley              6.7%
5                      Birmingham            -14.0%
```

2 `election2016`-->

```
        local_authority_name pre2016 post2016
0                       Adur     CON      CON
1               Amber Valley     CON      CON
2                     Barnet     NOC      NOC
3      Basingstoke and Deane     CON      CON
4                  Brentwood     CON      CON
```

3 `IMD2015`-->

```
                              IMD_decile
local_authority_name                    

Barking and Dagenham            2.600000
Barnet                          5.914692
Barnsley                        3.931973
Barrow-in-Furness               4.040816
Basildon                        5.209091
Basingstoke and Deane           7.678899
Bassetlaw                       5.042857
Bath and North East Somerset    7.400000
```

I want to get as follows:

```
   local_authority_name    dif_per_2013-2016    pre2016   post2016    IMD_decile
(...)
5    Barking and Dagenham             61.0%     NaN       NaN         2.600000
6                  Barnet             -8.4%     NOC       NOC         5.914692
7                Barnsley            -42.8%     NaN       NaN         NaN
8       Barrow-in-Furness               NaN     NaN       NaN         4.040816
9    Basingstoke and Deane              NaN     CON       CON         7.678899
(...)
```

I have tried with:

```
df_list = [df_total_per_dif, election2016, IMD2015]
df_concat = pd.concat(df_list)
df_final = df_concat.groupby('local_authority_name')['dif_per_2013-2016',' pre2016', 'post2016', 'IMD_decile'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x)).reset_index()
```

But I don't know how to change the function `lambda`to get what I need.

Comment: You need `merge` instead of concat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `local_authority_name` as the index for each of the DataFrames, and then call `pd.concat`:

```
df_list = [df_total_per_dif, election2016, IMD2015]
df_list = [df.set_index('local_authority_name') for df in df_list]
df_final = pd.concat(df_list, axis=1)
```

For example,

```
import pandas as pd
pd.options.display.width = 10000
df_total_per_dif = pd.DataFrame( {'dif_per_2013-2016': ['61.0%', '-8.4%', '-42.8%', '-45.1%', '6.7%', '-14.0%'], 'local_authority_name': ['Barking and Dagenham', 'Barnet', 'Barnsley', 'Bath and North East Somerset', 'Bexley', 'Birmingham']})

election2016 = pd.DataFrame({'local_authority_name': ['Adur', 'Amber Valley', 'Barnet', 'Basingstoke and Deane', 'Brentwood'], 'post2016': ['CON', 'CON', 'NOC', 'CON', 'CON'], 'pre2016': ['CON', 'CON', 'NOC', 'CON', 'CON']})

IMD2015 = pd.DataFrame({'IMD_decile': [2.6, 5.914692, 3.931973, 4.040816, 5.209091, 7.678899, 5.042857, 7.4], 'local_authority_name': ['Barking and Dagenham', 'Barnet', 'Barnsley', 'Barrow-in-Furness', 'Basildon', 'Basingstoke and Deane', 'Bassetlaw', 'Bath and North East Somerset']})


df_list = [df_total_per_dif, election2016, IMD2015]
df_list = [df.set_index('local_authority_name') for df in df_list]
df_final = pd.concat(df_list, axis=1)

print(df_final)
```

yields

```
                             dif_per_2013-2016 post2016 pre2016  IMD_decile
Adur                                       NaN      CON     CON         NaN
Amber Valley                               NaN      CON     CON         NaN
Barking and Dagenham                     61.0%      NaN     NaN    2.600000
Barnet                                   -8.4%      NOC     NOC    5.914692
Barnsley                                -42.8%      NaN     NaN    3.931973
Barrow-in-Furness                          NaN      NaN     NaN    4.040816
Basildon                                   NaN      NaN     NaN    5.209091
Basingstoke and Deane                      NaN      CON     CON    7.678899
Bassetlaw                                  NaN      NaN     NaN    5.042857
Bath and North East Somerset            -45.1%      NaN     NaN    7.400000
Bexley                                    6.7%      NaN     NaN         NaN
Birmingham                              -14.0%      NaN     NaN         NaN
Brentwood                                  NaN      CON     CON         NaN
```

---

Alternatively,

```
df_list = [df_total_per_dif, election2016, IMD2015]
df_final = df_list[0]
for df in df_list[1:]:
    df_final = pd.merge(df_final, df, on='local_authority_name', how='outer')
```

also works. Notice, however there is a slight difference in the result -- the first method returns a DataFrame with the `local_authority_name`s in the index, while the second method returns a DataFrame with a `local_authority_name` column. Simply call `reset_index` on the first result to move the `local_authority_name` into a column if you so wish.

---

For small DataFrames, such as your example, the first method (`using_concat`) is faster. 
For larger DataFrames, iteratively merging may be faster. For example, with the following 100000-row DataFrames:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
pd.options.display.width = 10000
N = 100000
def make_names(N):
    names = np.arange(2*N)
    np.random.shuffle(names)
    names = list(map(str, names[:N]))
    return names

df_total_per_dif = pd.DataFrame(
    {'dif_per_2013-2016': np.random.randint(10, size=N), 
     'local_authority_name': make_names(N)})

election2016 = pd.DataFrame({
    'local_authority_name': make_names(N), 
    'post2016': ['CON']*N, 'pre2016': ['CON']*N})

IMD2015 = pd.DataFrame({
    'IMD_decile': np.random.randint(10, size=N), 
    'local_authority_name': make_names(N)})

def using_concat(df_list):
    df_list = [df.set_index('local_authority_name') for df in df_list]
    df_final = pd.concat(df_list, axis=1)
    return df_final

def using_merge(df_list):
    df_final = df_list[0]
    for df in df_list[1:]:
        df_final = pd.merge(df_final, df, on='local_authority_name', how='outer')
    return df_final

df_list = [df_total_per_dif, election2016, IMD2015]
```

`using_merge` is ~70% faster than `using_concat`:

```
In [88]: %timeit using_merge(df_list)
1 loop, best of 3: 264 ms per loop

In [89]: %timeit using_concat(df_list)
1 loop, best of 3: 455 ms per loop

In [90]: 455/264
Out[90]: 1.7234848484848484
```

The method that is faster for you may depend on many other factors. If
performance is important, be sure to run benchmarks on your own machine with
your own data.

Comment: the performance issue is interesting, i would have assumed that merge and concat were implemented the same way